# Models -> has_many -> Twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations, has-many, has-many-through

So I have a somewhat confusing relationship here, between a Note, Group, and User. And I ended up with has_many twice in my model. But I'm currently focused on the Note & Group relationship.

Background: A Group can have a note. A User can also have a note. Which is why my Note is polymorphic. However, I also created a join model called a Tag, so that a Note can belong to multiple groups. In my code though, I ended up with multiple 'has_many :notes'. See all of my code below. What would be the proper way to do something like this?

Thanks in advance!

#### note.rb

```
belongs_to :notable, :polymorphic => true
has_many :tags
has_many :groups, :through => :tags
```

#### user.rb

```
has_many :notes, :as => :notable
```

#### group.rb

```
has_many :notes, :as => :notable
has_many :tags
has_many :notes, :through => :tags
```

#### tag.rb

```
belongs_to :note
belongs_to :group
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to give it a different name.

```
class Group
  has_many :notes, :as => :notable
  has_many :tags
  has_many :tagged_notes, :class_name => 'Note', :through => :tags
end
```

If you only want a single note for the `:as => :notable` part (this wasn't very clear in your question), you could just do this:

```
class Group
  has_one :note, :as => :notable
  has_many :tags
  has_many :notes, :through => :tags
end
```

The names just have to be different. Although with `note` vs. `notes` it might not be very clear what the distinction is in other parts of your code.

Comment: Well, a group will always have many notes, not just one. 

What I want to do is this. Someone can write a note, and then check some boxes for which groups they want to apply the note to. So a Group can have lots of notes, and a single note can belong to many different groups. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll check into calling it a tagged_note I guess, not too familiar with that.